# I don't understand this Python sentence 'if tail else head'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I saw it from *Python Cookbook*:

```
def sum(items):
    head, *tail = items
    return head + sum(tail) if tail else head
items = [1, 10, 7, 4, 5, 9]
print(sum(items)) #36
```

It says it's some kind of clever recursive algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
A if PREDICATE else B
```

A is yielded if `PREDICATE` is true, otherwise B is yielded.

```
>>> 'A' if 1 < 2 else 'B'
'A'
>>> 'A' if 1 > 2 else 'B'
'B'
```

Answer (score 3):

`sum(tail)` is part of the expression as well.
The structure of this expression is:

```
result = Val1 if condition else Val2
```

and it equivalent to:

```
if (condition):
    result = Val1
else:
    result = Val2
```

Comment: So 'condition' in that if clause is 'tail'? But it's not a Boolean or at least I think it should be like 'if tail != []'.

Comment: in pyhotn, you can use each variable as condition, in this case, tail is False if its empty or None.

Comment: Any Python object, when used in a boolean context (that is at the place where boolean is finally expected) is interpreted as its *expected* boolean value. Empty strings and all containers are interpreted as `False`. Non-empty ones are interpreted as `True`. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations for details.

Answer (score 1):

In other words it can be written as:

```
if tail:
    return head + sum(tail)
else:
    return head
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still working on that 'tail' thing, I'm not sure if it's 'if tail = ![]', does 'tail' really work in Python?

Comment: `tail` isn't a command here; it's simply the tuple containing all but the first item of `items`.

Comment: Since `tail` is a list, `if tail:` is the same as `if tail != []:`

Answer (score 1):

It could be rewritten as following:

```
def sum(items):
    head + *tail = items
    while tail:
        return head + sum(tail)
```

1. 1(head) + sum(tail) - *as the new items*
2. 1 + 10(head) + sum(tail)
3. 1 + 10 + 7(head) + sum(tail)
4. 1 + 10 + 7 + 4(head) + sum(tail)
5. 1 + 10 + 7 + 4 + 5(head) + sum(tail)
6. 1 + 10 + 7 + 4 + 5 + 9(head) - *there are no tails anymore*